# They may take our Rileys, but they will never take our Riddles

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Another Riley Riddle, with a small difference...

> My prefix can mean my whole
>   My suffix is commodity control
>   Find a room for urgent infix removal
>   And a cheeky tipple is left for approval
>   As for my whole, it is so often sought
>   For its release and freedom of thought

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My prefix can mean my whole

> as in "women's lib"

My suffix is commodity control

> ration

Find a room for urgent infix removal
And a cheeky tipple is left for approval

> Find an "ER" for urgent surgery, and "libation" is left.

As for my whole, it is so often sought
For its release and freedom of thought

> liberation

The title is a reference to

> "they may take our lives, but they'll never take our freedom", from the film *Braveheart*.

Probably coincidentally, this question was posted on the UTC anniversary of

> [Lithuanian independence (1918)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_Independence_of_Lithuania).

Comment: Perfectly answered! Your suspicions were correct - any link to Lithuania is purely coincidental. Tick for you.